# Add recaptcha to ASP Web API Login (/Token)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, recaptcha, asp.net-identity-2

I've successfully added Google's re-captcha v2 to a few of my API controllers and front end app however I'm struggling to find how to do it for the inbuilt Identity Login (or rather, /Token) endpoint.

I was going to put it in ApplicationOAuthProvider under the Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials however this accepts context.UserName and context.password from OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext. I'm wondering where this is located so I can get it to accept an additional parameter (the g-captcha-response)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code.

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
     var formData = context.Request.ReadFormAsync().Result;
     var captchaResponse = formData.Get("g-recaptcha-response");
     var result= _captchaService.VerifyCaptcha(captchaResponse);
     ......
}
```

> Form Data Sample

[image]